# how to integrate SASS in an online code editor?

Tags: sass

I am developing a project where I have to create a code editor that can handle HTML, CSS, SASS, JAVASCRIPT, PHP. The problem is I do not know how to integrate SASS in a way so that the coder can write sass code in the editor and the sass files could be compiled to a CSS file just like it does typically. Please help.